# static const members of template classes

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class with a static const member:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T val) : t(val) {}

    static const int VALUE = 5;

    T t;
};
```

Let's say that somewhere in my code, I'm instantiating it using types int, char, and long. Now I want to access VALUE:

```
int main()
{
    int i1 = A<int>::VALUE;
    int i2 = A<char>::VALUE;
    int i3 = A<long>::VALUE;

    return 0;
}
```

Aren't all of the above identical ways to access the same thing? In cases like this, do others just choose a random type? Is there any way to avoid specifying the type?

Comment: No, different instantiations make different classes. I kind of see your point, but template classes need a type, even with `static const`.

Comment: I believe the reason for this is because you can have `static const T value` instead of specifying the `int` type.

Comment: @chris: Hm, I'm gonna back away from this one, there's some confusion I'm just not catching.

Comment: @GManNickG, I know the feeling oh so well.

Answer (score 6):

These are all numerical constants, sharing the same value, but belonging to different name spaces. So you can't avoid specifying the enclosing class (by instantiating the template), even though it's not really needed.

You can, however, move the `static const` definition into a class that `A<T>` will inherit from:

```
class A_Consts
{
  static const int VALUE = 5;
  ...
}; 

template<typename T>
class A : public A_Consts
{
...
};
```

Or, move the constant defintion outside the class, and enclose them both in a namesapce. Which seems like the better solution IMHO.

Comment: I have a similar situation except my static const involves several largish arrays that I don't want to copy for both size reasons and for logical reasons (VALUE pertains to the whole family of classes not to each instantiation separately).  This is my preferred solution.